# 404 page not found after installing ERPNext

Tags: erpnext, frappe

After installing ERPNext using the frappe/bench repository on Github or using Docker to a custom domain name, when I go to the website, I get the error: "404 page not found", and ERPNext is inaccessible. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

The deployment of ERPNext creates your custom site and another site `site1.localhost`, and even though the installation process sets the custom site as the default one, it does not do so for the Traefik container. So you must open the generated confirmation file `frappe-compose.yaml` (may have a different name if you changed the project name) and change the following line:

```
traefik.http.routers.frontend-http.rule: Host(`site1.localhost`)
```

To

```
traefik.http.routers.frontend-http.rule: Host(`type.the.correct.domain.name.here`)
```

Then run the following commands to redeploy ERPNext:

```
docker compose -p frappe down
docker compose -p frappe -f frappe-compose.yml up -d
```

Comment: Let's say I run it in a VM just for testing ... what would I have to put in `Host('..')`? I already tried the local IP address but that didn't work.

Comment: @nibbo you can put just "localhost" there, or you can make a new entry in /etc/hosts (on WIndows this is located in C:\Windows\System32\drivers) with a fictional domain name that maps to 127.0.0.1.

This assumes you're going to access ERPNext from just inside the VM, but if you want to run it on the host too, you should set the VM's network to use bridged networking in the hypervisor, also set that VM's IP address in your router, and then modify /etc/hosts but using the VM's IP address, not localhost. Or in the case you might set DNS entries in your router too.